# Date api for managing off days in an year?

Tags: java, datetime, date

I want to know the available api's for date in java in which the following functionality is implemented.

Calculating date from one date to N day skipping the mentioned off day(holidays).

Comment: I doubt anyone would write an api for such a simple thing. I suggest take the list of holidays & make the algorithm simply check & skip the dates while counting.

Comment: off days can be region/country specific.

Answer (score 3):

[ObjectLabs' `DateCalc` library](http://objectlabkit.sourceforge.net) offers holiday handling with [multiple algorithms](http://objectlabkit.sourceforge.net/algo.html) depending on what you want to do. It comes in two versions, a raw JDK version and a version built on top of [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) (which they recommend).

Answer (score 0):

Even though I commented otherwise, I actually found a [Java API](http://forums.dzone.com/java/2205-new-java-holiday-api.html). I failed to notice a download link, but the comments sure say there is one somewhere.

There is also a sourceforge project, called [JollyDay](http://jollyday.sourceforge.net/) regarding this.

Comment: Since the first post states that he wrote an API, I didn't read ahead. Thanks for pointing it out.