# calculate business days including holidays

Tags: java, date, calendar

i need to calculate the business days between two dates.
ex : we have holiday(in USA) on july4th. so if my dates are
date1 = 07/03/2012
date2 = 07/06/2012

no of business days b/w these dates should be 1 since july4th is holiday.

i have a below method to calclulate the business days which will only counts week ends but not holidays.
is there any way to calculate holidays also....please help me on this.

```
  public static int getWorkingDaysBetweenTwoDates(Date startDate, Date endDate) {  
    Calendar startCal;  
    Calendar endCal;  
    startCal = Calendar.getInstance();  
    startCal.setTime(startDate);  
    endCal = Calendar.getInstance();  
    endCal.setTime(endDate);  
    int workDays = 0;  

    //Return 0 if start and end are the same  
    if (startCal.getTimeInMillis() == endCal.getTimeInMillis()) {  
        return 0;  
    }  

    if (startCal.getTimeInMillis() > endCal.getTimeInMillis()) {  
        startCal.setTime(endDate);  
        endCal.setTime(startDate);  
    }  

    do {  
        startCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);  
        if (startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY   
       && startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY) {  
            ++workDays;  
        }  
    } while (startCal.getTimeInMillis() < endCal.getTimeInMillis());  

    return workDays;  
}
```

Comment: You need to keep track of the knowledge of which days are holidays manually, AFAIK there's no built in function for that. Also, who uses do-while in java these days??

Comment: First of all you will need a list of all the holidays in a year beacuse no java class (i.e. `Locale` specific class) provides this functionality. Then you will need to find how many from this list fall between the dates specified which is fairly straight-forward. Then you can delete that many days from the result of your above code.

Comment: thanks for ur reply. let's say if i have a list which contains all the holidays, can u please suggest me how to use that list or how to check that list dates in the condition.

Comment: Duplicate of the Question [Date api for managing off days in an year?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8295442/642706) but this one has better answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's pretend you have a list containing all the holidays, as you mentioned.

```
ArrayList<Integer> holidays = ...
```

Just add a condition to your `if` condition in your `do-while`:

```
do {
          startCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
          if (startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY
          && startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY
          && !holidays.contains((Integer) startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR))) {
              ++workDays;
          }
} while (startCal.getTimeInMillis() < endCal.getTimeInMillis());
```

For simplicity's sake, I've assumed `holiday` contains dates in the format identical to `Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR`.

Comment: thank you so much...i don't know how i missed this simple logic. but here instead of Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR i am comparing it with the Calendar.getTime() which returns the full date. it working fine now

Comment: Cheers, glad to be of service.

Comment: It's worth noting both examples here will calculate 1 day for the difference of 1 millisecons or more.  Use a day_of_year and year comparison on the loop instead.

Answer (score 13):

Since the accepted answer still uses the obsolete `Calendar` class – here's my two cents using the newer Java Date and Time API available in the `java.time` package.

You have to get the dates of the holidays from somewhere, there is no standard Java library for it. That would be too localized anyway, since holidays heavily depend on your country and region (except for widely known holidays, such as Christmas or Easter).
You could get them from a holiday API, for instance. In the code below, I've hardcoded them as a `Set` of `LocalDate`s.

#### Java 9

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2012, 3, 7);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2012, 6, 7);

// I've hardcoded the holidays as LocalDates
// and put them in a Set
final Set<LocalDate> holidays = Set.of(
    LocalDate.of(2018, 7, 4)
);
// For the sake of efficiency, I also put the business days into a Set.
// In general, a Set has a better lookup speed than a List.
final Set<DayOfWeek> businessDays = Set.of(
    MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY
);

List<LocalDate> allDates =

    // Java 9 provides a method to return a stream with dates from the
    // startdate to the given end date. Note that the end date itself is
    // NOT included.
    startDate.datesUntil(endDate)

        // Retain all business days. Use static imports from
        // java.time.DayOfWeek.*
        .filter(t -> businessDays.contains(t.getDayOfWeek()))

        // Retain only dates not present in our holidays list
        .filter(t -> !holidays.contains(t))

         // Collect them into a List. If you only need to know the number of
         // dates, you can also use .count()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

#### Java 8

The method `LocalDate.datesUntil` is not available in Java 8, so you have to obtain a stream of all dates between those two dates in a different manner. We must first count the total number of days in between using the `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between` method.

```
long numOfDaysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate);
```

Then we must generate a sequence of integers exactly as long as the number of days between the start and end date, and then create `LocalDate`s from it, starting at the start date.

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
    .limit(numOfDaysBetween)
    .mapToObj(startDate::plusDays)
```

Now we have a `Stream<LocalDate>`, and you can then use the remaining part of the Java 9 code. You also need to replace the usage of `Set.of()`, because it's not available in Java 8. Probably by `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(MONDAY...FRIDAY))`.

Answer (score 8):

## Nager.Date

You can use the [JSON API](http://date.nager.at/Api) of [Nager.Date](https://github.com/nager/Nager.Date) project. It supports USA, Canada and Europe. The data available for every year you can save the information in your own database.

**Example**

```
//https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyValue value = mapper.readValue(new URL("http://date.nager.at/api/v1/get/US/2017"), PublicHoliday[].class);
```

**PublicHoliday.class**

```
public class PublicHoliday
{
    public String date;
    public String localName;
    public String name;
    public String countryCode;
    public Boolean fixed;
    public Boolean countyOfficialHoliday;
    public Boolean countyAdministrationHoliday;
    public Boolean global;
    public String[] counties;
    public int launchYear;
}
```

Example JSON data retrieved.

```json
[
  {
    "date": "2017-01-01",
    "localName": "New Year's Day",
    "name": "New Year's Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": true,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": true,
    "counties": null,
    "launchYear": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-01-16",
    "localName": "Martin Luther King, Jr. Day",
    "name": "Martin Luther King, Jr. Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": true,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": true,
    "counties": null,
    "launchYear": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-01-20",
    "localName": "Inauguration Day",
    "name": "Inauguration Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": true,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": false,
    "counties": [
      "US-DC",
      "US-LA",
      "US-MD",
      "US-VA"
    ],
    "launchYear": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-02-20",
    "localName": "Washington's Birthday",
    "name": "Presidents' Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": true,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": true,
    "counties": null,
    "launchYear": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-05-29",
    "localName": "Memorial Day",
    "name": "Memorial Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": true,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": true,
    "counties": null,
    "launchYear": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-07-04",
    "localName": "Independence Day",
    "name": "Independence Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": true,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": true,
    "counties": null,
    "launchYear": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-09-04",
    "localName": "Labor Day",
    "name": "Labor Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": true,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": true,
    "counties": null,
    "launchYear": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-09-09",
    "localName": "Columbus Day",
    "name": "Columbus Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": true,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": false,
    "counties": [
      "US-AL",
      "US-AZ",
      "US-CO",
      "US-CT",
      "US-DC",
      "US-GA",
      "US-ID",
      "US-IL",
      "US-IN",
      "US-IA",
      "US-KS",
      "US-KY",
      "US-LA",
      "US-ME",
      "US-MD",
      "US-MA",
      "US-MS",
      "US-MO",
      "US-MT",
      "US-NE",
      "US-NH",
      "US-NJ",
      "US-NM",
      "US-NY",
      "US-NC",
      "US-OH",
      "US-OK",
      "US-PA",
      "US-RI",
      "US-SC",
      "US-TN",
      "US-UT",
      "US-VA",
      "US-WV"
    ],
    "launchYear": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-11-10",
    "localName": "Veterans Day",
    "name": "Veterans Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": false,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": true,
    "counties": null,
    "launchYear": null
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-12-23",
    "localName": "Thanksgiving Day",
    "name": "Thanksgiving Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": true,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": true,
    "counties": null,
    "launchYear": 1863
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-12-25",
    "localName": "Christmas Day",
    "name": "Christmas Day",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "fixed": true,
    "countyOfficialHoliday": true,
    "countyAdministrationHoliday": true,
    "global": true,
    "counties": null,
    "launchYear": null
  }
]
```

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names always start with lowercase.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any code samples or anything like that, but I did some searching for you and came across this Stack Overflow thread that has some links to web services that can return holiday dates for you, which may help you get to where you need to be: [National holiday web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59934/national-holiday-web-service)

The top answer in that thread links to this web service: http://www.holidaywebservice.com/

I'm not sure if using a web service for this type of thing is overkill or not, but surely there is a better way. I apologize, I am not the most experienced programmer so I can't help you as much as I'd like to.

Comment: It's not really overkill.  You need to be getting the information from *somewhere* else as it's always subject to change.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way I've found is using some math (borrowing from the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600034/calculate-number-of-weekdays-between-two-dates-in-java/44942039#44942039) post):

```
public static int totalBusinessDaysBetween(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(start, "Start date must not be null");
    Objects.requireNonNull(end, "End date must not be null");
    long daysBetweenWithoutWeekends = calculateNumberOfDaysBetweenMinusWeekends(start, end);
    final Set<LocalDate> holidayForYearRange = getUSFederalHolidayForYearRange(start.getYear(), end.getYear());
    for (LocalDate localDate : holidayForYearRange) {
        if (localDate.isAfter(start) && localDate.isBefore(end)) {
            daysBetweenWithoutWeekends--;
        }
    }
    return (int) daysBetweenWithoutWeekends;
}
```

And:

```
private static long calculateNumberOfDaysBetweenMinusWeekends(LocalDate start, LocalDate end) {

    final DayOfWeek startW = start.getDayOfWeek();
    final DayOfWeek endW = end.getDayOfWeek();

    final long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end);
    final long daysWithoutWeekends = days - 2 * ((days + startW.getValue()) / 7);

    //adjust for starting and ending on a Sunday:
    return daysWithoutWeekends + (startW == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ? 1 : 0) + (endW == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ? 1 : 0);
}
```

I put something more complete together [here](https://github.com/jimador/fun-time).